# how to update json data using flutter

Tags: json, flutter

how to update JSON value. I am using flutter with a REST API to change the data but I'm struggling how to refresh my JSON data  sorry friends I don't know much about the flutter so please help me out about it please find JSON'S Object below:

```
{
id: 1,
clef: "Y8F5eEo0",
IndiceSensibilite: "0.04",
Objectif: "1.00"
}
```

I want to update the value of IndiceSensibilite using a textField.
I m here for more clarification. 
i will be very thankful if there's someone who gonna help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the JSON into an Object, make your modifications and back to JSON:

```
import 'dart:convert'; // make sure you imported this library


String jsonValue = '{"id": 1, "clef": "Y8F5eEo0", "indiceSensibilite": "0.04", "objectif": "1.00" }'; // original JSON
```

Use a Future to convert it into Object:

```
Future<ToObject> jsonToObject() async {
    var parse = json.decode(jsonValue);
    return ToObject.parseJson(parse);
}
```

and your Object (ToObject in my case) will have the following model and methods:

```
class ToObject {
  int id;
  String clef;
  String indiceSensibilite;
  String objectif;

  ToObject({this.id, this.clef, this.indiceSensibilite, this.objectif});

  factory ToObject.parseJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ToObject(
      id: json['id'], clef: json['clef'], indiceSensibilite: json['indiceSensibilite'], objectif: json['objectif']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'clef': clef, 'indiceSensibilite': indiceSensibilite, 'objectif': objectif};
}
```

I used a FutureBuilder to get the data, modify the value and back to JSON:

```
FutureBuilder<ToObject>(
     future: jsonToObject(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              var object = snapshot.data;
              object.indiceSensibilite = "43.00";
              return Text(json.encode(object.toJson()));
          } else {
              return Text("Loading...");
          }
     },
)
```

Your end result is a modified JSON to use as you wish:

[image: Modified JSON]

Comment: my pleasure! happy to know that's what you needed.

Comment: If I have a set of model and just want to update only certain part, how does it work??